# trouble with long running thread implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I implement long running thread in this way:

```
public class LongRunningWorker implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    // get a job from threadsafe job queue and run it.
                    Job job = jobQueue_.removeJob();
                    execute(job);
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(workerSleepSec_);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally {
                LOGGER.info("runner quit");
                // Clean up
                cleanup();
            }
        }
}
```

In the main function I added them in a executor:

```
ExecutorService executor_ = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfThreads);
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
            executor_.submit(new LongRunningWorker(jobQueue));
}
```

It turns out the LongRunningWorker is not always running. After several hours executing, I found out all those LongRunningWorker exits. Why is it? If I want to make it always running, How to do that?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing but it seems you are not using threads correctly. Why do you need to keep threads alive. Just use a thread when a new job comes.

Comment: You are using a ThreadPool with default parameters that are not to your liking. See the discussion on keep-alive times in [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: Hint: java coding style guides do **not** like "_" chars in variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you don't understand the point of the [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html): there is no need to "manually" keep those threads alive. The **framework** will do that for you.

In other words: the idea of that ExecutorService is that you simply continue to submit tasks into it. And the underlying implementation manages threads for you. And when you go for the [fixed thread pool service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)), rest assured that you will always be running with the given count of threads.

Edit: given your comment - if your main focus is about "resources" that need to be managed along with the threads using them; then I see two options:

1. Instead of using the ExecutorService framework you do your complete own management implementation (doesnt sound like a great idea, does it)
2. You make sure that your tasks can request "free" resources: meaning you keep the ExecutorService, but add some own code to manage the resources the tasks will need to their job **independent** of the ExecutorService threads.

Edit: further thinking about your problem ... you should check if there aren't *other* problems (like uncaught exceptions) that cause your threads to stop. Maybe you could try catching for a wider range of exceptions.

Comment: There is a resource with each worker. How to bond it with the thread and available to each worker?

Comment: Given Current implementation, is there a way to make it work?

Comment: No idea for that part, but another thought regarding your current problem. Let me know if that helps.